# Tensor product and Direct product.

Tags: vector-spaces, tensor-products

Is the direct product of two vector spaces (over the same field) just the tensor product of two vector spaces over $\mathbb{Z}$?

Am I right in thinking that essentially we would use the tensor product to add together pairs of the Cartesian product of our vector spaces over some ring with 'the same simplifications we would ask for in direct product viewed as a vector space', and if this ring happens to be $\mathbb{Z}$ then we have exactly the direct product?

Comment: What's for you "direct product of two vector spaces"?

Comment: I guess the tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$! Haha.

Comment: Hehe...well, then your question has a rather tautological, and pretty boring, answer...Observe though that if you take the tensor product over $\;\Bbb Z\;$ then you're considering the vector spaces merely as abelian group: what about the structure of vector spaces?

Comment: In all serious though, I guess that is how I was taught what the  direct product was. I'm just wondering why I wasn't told about the tensor product, if it encompasses direct product.

Comment: Direct product of two vectors spaces $V, W$ is by definition $V \times W$, the set of all ordered pairs.

Answer (score 4):

No, certainly not. If $V$ is $m$-dimensional (say $e_1, \ldots, e_m$ is a basis) and $W$ is $n$-dimensional (with basis $f_1, \ldots, f_n$), then $V \otimes W$ is $mn$-dimensional, with basis $e_i \otimes f_j$. On the other hand, $V \oplus W$ (what I and most of the world understand by "direct product") is $(m+n)$-dimensional, effectively with basis $e_1, \ldots, e_m, f_1, \ldots, f_n$.

Tensors $V \otimes W$ are universal recipients of *bilinear maps*: there is a bilinear map $i: V \times W \to V \otimes W$ such that for any bilinear map $g:V \times W \to U$, there is a unique linear map $\phi: V \otimes W \to U$ making the evident triangle commute.

Comment: The author of the question speaks about tensor products over $\mathbb{Z}$. What you write here holds for the tensor product over the field the vector spaces is defined on.

Comment: @user44400 You're right; I must have elided over that on first reading (but the confusion of the author seemed to be confused at a more basic level).

Answer (score 2):

No, for example let $V$ be a nonzero vector space, and let $W$ be the vector space just consisting of zero.  The direct product of $V$ and $W$ is $$V \times W = V \times \{0\} \cong V$$ while on the other hand $V \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}W$ is the zero vector space, because elements in here are sums of the form $v \otimes w : v \in V, w \in W$.  But every such term is zero.